# Cambiar un campo específico en Firebase con Android

Tags: android-studio, firebase, estructuras-de-datos

soy nuevo programando. Quería saber si alguien me puede explicar como podría llamar en Firebase al último del historial que creé. Solo necesito llamar al mas reciente. Desde ya, muchas gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Podes usar el `limitToLast()` y ponerlo en 1 para traer el ultimo elemento del nodo

```
ref.child("history").limitToLast(1).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
   //Tu dato
   String cadenaJson = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class); //Esto te devuelve toda la ultima clave
  }

  @Override
  public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    System.out.println("The read failed: " + databaseError.getCode());
  }
});
```

Desde la documentacion

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data?hl=es-419

> Las consultas limitToFirst() y limitToLast() se utilizan para definir
>   una cantidad máxima de elementos secundarios que se sincronizarán para
>   una devolución de llamada específica.